# How to overlay an image onto a section?

Tags: html, css, css-position

So i am a complete newbie when It comes to coding. I am currently trying to make a website, but I have reached a dead end. As the question above summarizes, I am trying to overlay a picture on a background with a color different from white. The picture needs to extend beyond the colored background and “reach” the white background. I have submitted an image which better explains what I am going for.

I have tried to make a section with the container class an insert the image in it but this restricts the size of the image to the size of the section.m

[image: Image of what i am going for]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take some time to read the SO guidelines and edit your question to meet the guidelines. Always include a minimal reproducable code snippet (Ctrl + M) to show your code. State what you already tried and where exactly you're stuck with solving the issue on your own.

Comment: I've given a few other ways to go about doing this if a special situation arises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proberly easiest way to let an image move outside of the container, is to give it a negative margin. In this example, I added a negative margin of `margin-top: -60px;`. Including the 10px padding, it moves 50px above the container.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

section div {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

section img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg">
</section>
```

Comment: I have one more question - How would you make the box with text inside the other box like the picture?

Comment: simply use a div with `background-color`. Let me edit the code to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using the following two methods:

### Translate or Translate Y

> The `translate()` method moves an element from its current position (according to the parameters given for the X-axis and the Y-axis).

[CSS 2D Transforms](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

```css
section {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: wheat;
  height: 200px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.img-container {
  width: 300px;
  transform: translateY(-40px) /* The Translate Y Property*/
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <h1>BUSINESS EVENTS</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=Random+Image" >
  </div>
</section>
```

### Margin

Just as I used a negative pixel value for the Y-Axis, I could do something similar for margin.

```
.img-container {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

## Why?

The reason I would choose these two specifically is because

- There is only one property that needs changing making this quite simple
- It doesn't hinder the document flow

There are a few others such as the position relative property

```
.img-container {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
}
```

But I prefer to keep it simple.